# Can't toggle boolean in another class in class

Tags: java, boolean

I can't toggle boolean in another class in a class. I am not very experienced with Java.  Here is the code:

```
if (me.test.firstplugin.testing.moretesting.thisboolean = true)
{
    me.test.firstplugin.testing.moretesting.thisboolean = false;
}
else
{
    me.test.firstplugin.testing.moretesting.thisboolean = true;
}
```

Please help!

Comment: `if (me.test.firstplugin.testing.moretesting.thisboolean = true){` will set the value to true. Use "==" to compare values.

Comment: The best way to toggle a boolean is to say `b = !b`. No need for if statements.

Answer (score 2):

You are not toggling the variable, just setting that to true all the time....

```
if (me.test.firstplugin.testing.moretesting.thisboolean = true)
```

that is setting the var **me.test.firstplugin.testing.moretesting.thisboolean**  to **true**

since that is a boolean you an just do:

```
if (me.test.firstplugin.testing.moretesting.thisboolean)
```

no need to

```
me.test.firstplugin.testing.moretesting.thisboolean == true
```

Comment: Didn't work, just keeps setting the boolean to true. I have a public void named "testity", the boolean is inside there. The "testity" void runs every 1 millisecond.

Answer (score 2):

You have to give == instead of = while checking

```
if (me.test.firstplugin.testing.moretesting.thisboolean == true){
        me.test.firstplugin.testing.moretesting.thisboolean = false;
}
   else
{
        me.test.firstplugin.testing.moretesting.thisboolean = true;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work, just keeps setting the boolean to true. I have a public void named "testity", the boolean is inside there. The "testity" void runs every 1 millisecond.

Comment: You don't actually need to check `thisboolean == true`... Just test whether `thisboolean` *is* `true`:  `if (me.test.firstplugin.testing.moretesting.thisboolean)`